# Add custom directives to wsgi.conf on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to add ProxyPass directive to default wsgi.conf. I tried running `sed` command in `container_commands` script, but it seems to be called before wsgi.conf is created by deploy scripts. I found that i can drop custom hooks in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post` directory, but this method is not officially supported.

Answer (score 2):

I wish I could find something more official, but it seems people are putting a wsgi.conf into their project, and using a `container_commands` script to move it to the appropriate location (which is not `/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf`, though it does end up replacing `/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf` in the end!):

```
container_commands:
  04_wsgireplace:
    command: "cp wsgi.conf ../wsgi.conf"
```

or

```
container_commands:
  04_wsgireplace:
    command: "cp .ebextensions/wsgi.conf ../wsgi.conf"
```

Depends on where in your project you've stored `wsgi.conf`, I assume.  Looks like the script is being run from the app directory.  I'm about to try it myself (for a flask project), and I'll report back!

There's a very related question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/785735/aws-elastic-beans-container-commands).

(References: [1](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=182431),[2](https://rickchristianson.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/updating-wsgi-automatically-in-amazon-aws/),[3](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=128232))

Update: I tried it out (with wsgi.conf in .ebextensions), and it worked (for me).

Comment: `cp .ebextensions/wsgi.conf ../wsgi.conf` works ... somehow absolute path does not work

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at another solution that builds on issue where default wsgi.conf needs to be extended.   The concept comes from this blog [post deploy](https://junkheap.net/blog/2013/05/20/elastic-beanstalk-post-deployment-scripts/)

```
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post
    ignoreErrors: true
  mv_post_appddeploy_script:
    command: mv /tmp/99_wsgi_conf.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post
files:
  "/tmp/99_wsgi_conf.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      service httpd stop
      echo "WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}" >> /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf
      service httpd start
```

I think this is a more elegant solution - extend default rather than ignore.  Can be made more sophisticated when required.

Comment: I finally found my mistake,  using .conf instead of .config for ebextensions file.   Solution now fully works as wanted.